# HandlebarJS Using result of another property as name for somewhere else

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

So, I'm trying to get my head around handlebar JS and I'm running in to some unknowns for me.

Say I have the following JS object.

```
{{"labels": ["arms", "leg", "chest"], "arms-avg": 33, "leg-avg": 13, "chest-avg": 55}}
```

I want to do something like the following, but not sure how

```
{{#each labels}}
    <div>{{this}} + '-avg'</div>
{{/each}}
```

Hopefully that makes sense, but please let me know if you I haven't been too clear

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{#each labels as |label|}}
    <div>{{this}}-avg  => {{testHelper this}}
{{/each}}

Handlebars.registerHelper('testHelper', function(key, options) {
    return options.data.root[key +'-avg'];
});
```

will return the value of the key

```
<div>arms-avg  => 33
<div>leg-avg  => 13
<div>chest-avg  => 55
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for that. If I wanted to just get the value with the same name, and not key +'-avg', do I use the same help, but and just remove the string, or is there an easier way?